# Why RowObjectEventArgs gives a wrong row?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress, handler

I have a gridcontrol and there is a column named Accepted, a `RepositoryItemCheckEdit` is on this column. 
I have below eventHandler for this column when row is updated:

```
private void RowUpdateEventHandler(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.RowObjectEventArgs e)
{    
  e.Row...
}
```

I have four rows in the grid: Row1, Row2, Row3 and Row4. I check Accepted column for the 4 rows one by one. But I find:

1. After I check Row1 Accepted, e.Row is null;
2. After I check Row2 Accepted, e.Row is Row2;
3. After I check Row3 Accepted, e.Row is Row2 or null - why the value of this e.Row is so unstable?

I don't know much about the RowObjectEventArgs, but I do expect, after I check Row1 Accepted, e.Row is Row1; after I check Row2 Accepted, e.Row is Row2; ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that this is because the RowUpdate event happens when you take focus off of the row, not when you check the box.  You probably want to look at the devexpress support forum post here: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q279955.aspx